# ListView doesn't scroll smoothly when I add AdView as an item

Tags: android, listview, scroll, adview

I am implementing the `Google Ads` in my android app. Mostly I am interested in implementing the ads inside a `ListView`. For example every 10-th element I display an item containing the `AdView`. It will be only one Ad that it is displayed a various number of time. Below is my code. It works, the ads are displayed in the `ListView`, the app doesn't crash, but there is one small problem. When I scroll the list, the moment it comes to item displaying `AdView`, it seize for a bit, the scroll isn't so smoothly. I have tried the list without displaying ads and the scroll is fine.

```
   NewsHomeAdapter(ArrayList<AdMobInterfaceList> items, Context context) {

        this.items = items;
        this.mContext = context;
        // member variable
        // iteron mbi objektet e bizneset dhe kontrollon cfare tipi eshte. Ne
        // varesi te tipit theret adapterin e tij
        for (AdMobInterfaceList item : items) {

            if (item.getType() == 0) {
                rows.add(new AdMobItemAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(mContext),
                        item, mContext));
            }
            if (item.getType() == 1) {
                rows.add(new NewsItemAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(mContext),
                        item, mContext));
            }


        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return rows.get(position).getViewType();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    public void updateNjoftimeList(ArrayList<AdMobInterfaceList> items) {


        for (AdMobInterfaceList item : items) {

            if (item.getType() == 0) {
                rows.add(new AdMobItemAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(mContext),
                        item, mContext));
            }
            if (item.getType() == 1) {
                rows.add(new NewsItemAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(mContext),
                        item, mContext));
            }


        }

        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    public void updateNjoftimeFilterList(ArrayList<AdMobInterfaceList> items) {

        //mNjoftime.clear();
        //mNjoftime.addAll(newList);


        rows.clear();

        for (AdMobInterfaceList item : items) {

            if (item.getType() == 0) {
                rows.add(new AdMobItemAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(mContext),
                        item, mContext));
            }
            if (item.getType() == 1) {
                rows.add(new NewsItemAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(mContext),
                        item, mContext));
            }
        }

        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return rows.get(position).getView(convertView);
    }
}
```

NewsItemAdapter.class

```
public class NewsItemAdapter implements ListsItemInterface {

    final private AdMobInterfaceList item;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;

    public NewsItemAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, AdMobInterfaceList item, Context context) {
        this.item = item;
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public View getView(View convertView) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_home_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tittle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tittle);
            holder.category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.published_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.published_time);
            holder.news_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");

        holder.tittle.setTypeface(typeFace);
        holder.desc.setTypeface(typeFace);
        holder.published_time.setTypeface(typeFace);
        holder.category.setTypeface(typeFace);

        holder.tittle.setText(((NewsItem) item).getTittle());
        holder.desc.setText(((NewsItem) item).getDesc());
        holder.published_time.setText(((NewsItem) item).getPublishedTimeString());
        holder.category.setText(((NewsItem) item).getCategory());

        //holder.news_image.getLayoutParams().width = 0;

        if (!((NewsItem) item).getImageUrl().isEmpty()) {
            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.news_image, ((NewsItem) item).getImageUrl(), R.drawable.watermark_ikub);
        } else {
            holder.news_image.getLayoutParams().width = 0;
        }
        return convertView;
    }


    public int getViewType() {
        return 1;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView news_image=null;
        TextView tittle;
        TextView desc;
        TextView published_time;
        TextView category;

    }
}
```

AdMobItemAdapter.class

```
public class AdMobItemAdapter implements ListsItemInterface {

    final private AdMobInterfaceList item;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;

    public AdMobItemAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, AdMobInterfaceList item, Context context) {
        this.item = item;
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public View getView(View convertView) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        //we have a don't have a converView so we'll have to create a new one
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_mob_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder((AdView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.adView)) ;
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            //get the holder back out
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.ad.setFocusable(false);
       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("134BDAE1F7410A5CD779E89C5C8CBC20")
                .build();
        holder.ad.loadAd(((AdMobItem)item).getAdRequest());

        return convertView;
    }


    public int getViewType() {
        return 0;
    }

    public  class ViewHolder {
        public AdView ad;


        public ViewHolder(AdView ad) {
            this.ad = ad;

        }
    }
}
```

These is the code that I have used for the adapter of the `ListView`.I think the reason is that I load the ad for every item. But I don't know how to handle this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Obviously it will not going to scroll smooth because everytime when you scroll, getView mathod from adapter will called and so that your ADRequest, try to load it only once by putting it in  if (convertView == null) block, and store it in holder,  and every time after that fetch it from holder, this might help you

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot, but still when the add appears for the first time, it gives the same problem.